# Form doesn't update while running button click event

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms, progress-bar, refresh

I'm trying to update a progress bar at the end of each method in Visual Basic, the problem is that label1.Text does not update itself at the start at each method but will update.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Const METHOD_COUNT = 4

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = METHOD_COUNT
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Method_One()
        Method_Two()
        Method_Three()
        Method_Four()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_One()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method One"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Two()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Two"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Three()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Three"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Four()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Four"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub
End Class
```

So basically when you run this, it will execute and update the progress bar nicely, but the label does not update. I think it might have something to do with multithreading and the fact the form does not get a constant update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "quick fix" is to add `Application.DoEvents()` before each call to `Sleep()`:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Const METHOD_COUNT = 4

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = METHOD_COUNT
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Method_One()
        Method_Two()
        Method_Three()
        Method_Four()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_One()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method One"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Two()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Two"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Three()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Three"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Four()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Four"
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The "**correct** fix" is that your "work" should not be done in the main UI thread, which is what you're doing be calling those methods from the button click handler.  Instead, you need to move the work to a background thread so that the UI can update itself.  Take a look at using the **BackgroundWorker()** control.  You call its ReportProgress() method which fires the ProgressChanged() event.  From that event it's safe to update the UI.  When the work in the background thread is complete you'll get a RunWorkerCompleted() event.  Note that you have to set the WorkerReportsProgress() property to True if you want to use the progress events:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Const METHOD_COUNT = 4

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = METHOD_COUNT
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Method_One()
        Method_Two()
        Method_Three()
        Method_Four()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_One()
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1, "Loading Method One")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Two()
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(2, "Loading Method Two")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Three()
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(3, "Loading Method Three")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Method_Four()
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(4, "Loading Method Four")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        Label1.Text = e.UserState
        ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Button1.Enabled = True
        MessageBox.Show("Done!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the value of the label is being changed, but the screen is not being updated have you tried the refresh method?

For example:

```
    Private Sub Method_Three()
        Label1.Text = "Loading Method Three"
        Label1.Refresh
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
        'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone else can explain why this is but i have always had to use the following to get Labels to update when they wouldn't otherwise:

```
Private Sub Method_Three()
    With Label1
        .Text = "Loading Method Three"
        .Refresh
    End With
    ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    'Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
End Sub
```